# Vertical align with Tailwind CSS across full screen div

Tags: html, css, user-interface, tailwind-css

How can I vertically align a div with Tailwind?
What I want:

```
-----------------------------------
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|             item1              |
|             item2              |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
-----------------------------------
```

What I currently have:

```
-----------------------------------
|             item1              |
|             item2              |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
-----------------------------------
```

HTML

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen my-auto items-center bgimg bg-cover">
  <h3 class="text-white">heading</h3>
  <button class="mt-2 bg-white text-black font-bold py-1 px-8 rounded m-2">
    call to action
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('https://d1ia71hq4oe7pn.cloudfront.net/photo/60021841-480px.jpg');
}
```

I have successfully centered on the secondary axis (left-right) with class `items-center`. Reading the documentation, I tried `align-middle` but it does not work. I have confirmed the divs have full height and `my-auto`.

I'm using this version of Tailwind: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7xnghf1m/2/

Comment: This is already pretty well documented in the TailwindCSS docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flexbox-align-items/#center

Comment: replace my-auto by justify-center

Comment: ```m-auto text-center``` worked fine for me.

Comment: In TailwindCSS we have two options Flexbox and CSSgrid. Tailwind using CSSgrid reach this simply with only one class. `place-items-center`
You can find the solution for the CSSgrid here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70552722/1238917

Answer (score 302, accepted):

You can also do

```html
<div class="flex h-screen">
  <div class="m-auto">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how? how does this work?? Please please explain. @Nartub

Comment: There's a lot of magic involving auto margins and flexbox, I suggest googling to get the whole details :)

Comment: @dhrumilbarot flex is applied only to the next div element (in this case, the one with class="m-auto"), h-screen sets the height to 100vh (100% of the view height) to give it the entire space of the screen to work with. m-auto sets the margins to auto, which pads it out and gives it that 'centered' look

Comment: @dhrumilbarot Bear in mind that magic isn't very readable (in code), specifying classes lets you and other devs know exactly what's going on and follows documentation standards.

Answer (score 110):

Partly referencing [@mythicalcoder 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807846/4957466) but using only the necessary classes provided by TailwindCss (Version 1.8.+):

- `flex` : To use a flex-div as container
- `h-screen` : To size the container-height to the viewport height.
- `justify-center` : To justify center (horizontal center) - *main axis* - [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content)
- `items-center` : To align the items to center (horizontal center)  - *cross axis* - [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items)

My Solution to center two text lines:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="flex h-screen justify-center items-center">
    <div class="text-center bg-blue-400"> <!-- ⬅️ THIS DIV WILL BE CENTERED -->
        <h1 class="text-3xl">HEADING</h1>
        <p class="text-xl">Sub text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this works until u have to scroll

Answer (score 40):

### Justify-Center and Items-Center

While Anders' answer solves the problem for this particular case, I think it's important to note that using `justify-center` and `items-center` is circumstantial.

Let's have a look at one of the examples from the [tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flexbox-justify-content/#center).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex justify-center bg-gray-100">
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

As we can see the above code centers the elements horizontally. The reason for this is because the justify-center class **centers the element on the flex container's main axis**.

This means that if we were to change the main axis to 'column' then we would get a different result.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex flex-col justify-center bg-gray-100">
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
  <div class="text-gray-800 text-center bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

Justify-Center and Items-Center centers the elements on the main axis and the cross axis, and they can be used in place of each other. They are the opposites of each other and will produce different results depending on what the current main axis is.

Answer (score 33):

I have tried to summarize different occurrences of centering the `divs`

#### Center divs in Column

###### For fit width

```
  <div class="bg-yellow-400 flex flex-col h-screen justify-center items-center">
    <div className="bg-green-500 p-2">item 1</div>
    <div className="bg-pink-500 p-2">item 2</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

###### For full width

```
  <div class="bg-yellow-400 flex flex-col h-screen justify-center items-center">
    <div className="bg-green-500 p-2 w-full flex justify-center">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div className="bg-pink-500 p-2 w-full text-center">item 2</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

---

#### Extra:

###### Center vertically split divs

```
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-green-500 p-2 text-4xl">
    <div class="bg-yellow-400 p-6">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-pink-500 p-2 text-4xl"><div class="bg-amber-400 p-6">Item 2</div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

###### Center horizontally split divs

```
<div class="flex h-screen">
  <div class="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-green-500 p-2 text-4xl">
    <div class="bg-yellow-400 p-6">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-pink-500 p-2 text-4xl"><div class="bg-amber-400 p-6">Item 2</div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

#### Center divs in Row

##### For fit height

```
<div>
  <div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-yellow-400">
    <div class="flex justify-center bg-green-500 p-2">item 1</div>
    <div class="bg-pink-500 p-2 text-center">item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

##### For full height

```
<div>
  <div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-yellow-400">
    <div class="flex h-full items-center bg-green-500 p-2">item 1</div>
    <div class="flex h-full items-center bg-pink-500 p-2">item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

According to the question, the "Items1", "Items2" should be both horizontally and vertically aligned.

**Horizontal** => text-center/justify-center

**Vertical** => items-center

Here is a sample code for producing a view similar to the ASCII image in the question.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative h-32 bg-blue-400">
  <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
    Item 1
    <br>
    Item 2
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

**A-1 - Solution: Flexbox**

Considering **Flexbox** and only using the classes provided by **TailwindCss** without adding a new div element:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

**check the result here:**
https://play.tailwindcss.com/HZIvf53Rcv

**A-2 - Solution: CSSgrid**

Besides **Flexbox** we have another choice that is **CSSgrid** using the classes provided by **TailwindCss**:

- `grid` : To create a grid container. [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#grid)
- `h-screen` : To size the container-height to the viewport height.
- `justify-items-center` : is equivalent to `justify-items: center;` in CSSgrid and it is centering grid items inside their grid track along the horizontal axis.  - [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-items)
- `items-center` : is equivalent to `align-items: center;` in CSSgrid and it is aligning the items inside their grid track to center along the vertical axis - [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items)

```html
<div class="grid justify-items-center items-center h-screen">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**check the result here:**
https://play.tailwindcss.com/UtW8Gmbvsk

**B-2 - Shorthand: CSSgrid**

There is a shorthand property in **CSSgrid** when you want to justify and align items with only one property, that is `place-items`.

`place-items: vertical-value(align) horizontal-value(justify);`

When both values vertical and horizontal are the same you can provide a single value.

`place-items: vertical-horizontal-value;`

In **TailwindCSS** there is a class for this. `place-items-center` which is equivalent to `place-items: center;` in CSS.

Hence if you want to use only one class for this aim you should do this:

```
<div class="grid h-screen place-items-center">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**check the result here:**
https://play.tailwindcss.com/jxIbYWN9Ad

Answer (score 6):

@bastiotutuama's answer is already good, however if there are other surrounding items then use align self utilities instead of items-center. [source](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-self)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bg-blue-500 flex justify-center h-screen">
    <div class="bg-red-300 self-start">
        <h1>
            Let us get you off the board <br>
            <span>Pursue what you wanted</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="mt-2 flex items-center">
            <a href="#" class="block bg-indigo-600 text-indigo-100 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase tracking-wide font-semibold">Get started</a>
            <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-300 text-gray-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase font-semibold">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-300 self-center">
        <h1>
            Let us get you off the board <br>
            <span>Pursue what you wanted</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="mt-2 flex items-center">
            <a href="#" class="block bg-indigo-600 text-indigo-100 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase tracking-wide font-semibold">Get started</a>
            <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-300 text-gray-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase font-semibold">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red-300 self-end">
        <h1>
            Let us get you off the board <br>
            <span>Pursue what you wanted</span>
        </h1>
        <div class="mt-2 flex items-center">
            <a href="#" class="block bg-indigo-600 text-indigo-100 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase tracking-wide font-semibold">Get started</a>
            <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-300 text-gray-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-sm uppercase font-semibold">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Navigation using React

[image]

```
<nav className="flex gap-8 items-center justify-center">
  <Link className=''>SHOP</Link>
  <Link className=''>BACKPACK</Link>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

For vertical center in Tailwind Grid
use class name:

> **self-center**

```
 <div class="self-center">
```

Comment: This example is either missing proper explanation, doesn't work or both.

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
<div class="flex justify-center items-center flex-col">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
</div>
```

However, this approach requires flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way and it works.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 h-screen">
<div class="bg-red-400 col-span-3 sm:col-span-1 flex">
    <div class="bg-blue-300 m-auto">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-span-3 bg-red-50 sm:col-span-2"></div>
```

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBImp.png)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing that worked for me was:

```
<div className="m-auto">
    <div className="text-center">

      <h3>
        Some text
      </h3>

      <button type="button">
        Some button
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>
```

To center multiple elements within another div with `text-center`

Answer (score 0):

Use class `justify-center` to align on the *main axis*. `align-middle` operates on the *cross axis*.

Comment: can you please update your answer with how the code looks in the container end the actual element you want to center

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<p className='place-items-center flex'>Yout text</p>
```