# How to align a div within a div using flex and flex-col Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, centering, tailwind-css

I'm trying to vertically center the div with a white border onto the div with a green background. Colors just for show. I cannot figure out why justify-center and items-center do not work. I know I can use margin to achieve what I want but I know there's a better way. I have tried referencing this SO post but have had no luck:[Reference Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056513/vertical-align-with-tailwind-css-across-full-screen-div)

Also, if there is a better solution to implement what I want I'm all ears.

My code:

```
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-coolGray-900">
    <div class="w-screen justify-center items-center h-screen bg-green-500 ">
        <div class="text-center text-white border-2 ">
            <h1 class="mb-10 text-6xl font-bold font-lato">Message Here</h1>
            <h2 class="mb-8 text-2xl font-semibold font-lato">More Detailed Message Here</h2>
            <button class="mx-auto btn btn-learn">Learn More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't displayed your `bg-green-500` class as `flex` - it will work when you do this.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Had to add "flex flex-col". I thought it would just inherit "flex flex-col" from parent. If you'd like to answer it, I will mark it right.

Comment: No worries, and answered :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't displayed your container class as `flex`, this is why your justifies aren't working.

- Add the class `flex` to your `bg-green-500` class.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-coolGray-900">
    <div class="flex w-screen justify-center items-center h-screen bg-green-500 ">
        <div class="text-center text-white border-2 w-screen">
            <h1 class="mb-10 text-6xl font-bold font-lato">Message Here</h1>
            <h2 class="mb-8 text-2xl font-semibold font-lato">More Detailed Message Here</h2>
            <button class="mx-auto btn btn-learn">Learn More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```