# Tailwind CSS center vertically and horizontally inside flex flex-col?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I've got the following code and have tried adding "justify-content", "align-middle", and others but still can't seem to get it to align the h5 and link in the middle of the containing div. Should I be structuring this another way, without using "flex" or "flex-col"?

```
<section id="cta-image-box"
         class="container mx-auto py-24 mt-32 mb-32">
    <div class="h-[335px] rounded-[40px] bg-slate-500 bg-bgCTA bg-cover bg-center bg-blend-multiply">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <h5 class="text-5xl font-bold text-white mb-10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor site <span class="text-gray-300">15% OFF</span> amet
            </h5>
            <a href="#"
               alt=""
               class="px-6 py-3 w-fit rounded-full bg-slate-200 text-gray-800 hover:bg-slate-800 hover:text-white">
                Discount Code
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `h-full`  and `place-content-center place-items-center` on wrapper div.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="cta-image-box" class="container mx-auto py-24 mt-32 mb-32">
    <div class="h-[335px] rounded-[40px] bg-slate-500 bg-bgCTA bg-cover bg-center bg-blend-multiply">
      <div class="h-full flex flex-col place-content-center text-center place-items-center">
        <h5 class="text-5xl font-bold text-white mb-10">
          Lorem ipsum dolor site <span class="text-gray-300">15% OFF</span> amet
        </h5>
        <a href="#" alt="" class="px-6 py-3 w-fit rounded-full bg-slate-200 text-gray-800 hover:bg-slate-800 hover:text-white">
                Discount Code
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63978856/2007927) which is already explained how to align vertically center quite clear.

Below, you can see how to apply it to your code. You should give these classes: `flex` `justify-center` `items-center`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="cta-image-box" class="container mx-auto py-24 mt-32 mb-32">
  <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-[335px] rounded-[40px] bg-slate-500 bg-bgCTA bg-cover bg-center bg-blend-multiply">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
      <h5 class="text-5xl font-bold text-white mb-10">
        Lorem ipsum dolor site <span class="text-gray-300">15% OFF</span> amet
      </h5>
      <a href="#" alt="" class="px-6 py-3 w-fit rounded-full bg-slate-200 text-gray-800 hover:bg-slate-800 hover:text-white">
          Discount Code
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```